# Highcharts: scroll for text area inside highcharts container; custom table inside highcharts container

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I was doing an implementation like in fiddle . [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdzpac2x/1/)

But I have more data to be added inside container. So it will be like in the following image.
[image]

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/gdzpac2x/1/
```

Is there any way to add scroll bar to the text box. Or it is ok to add a custom table to the container than this textbox with text and break statements. Is this possible with highcharts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling the `renderer` method you can set `useHTML` argument to `true` and apply `width`, `height` and `overflow` styles:

```
$('#container').highcharts( 
...,
function(chart) {
    var text = chart.renderer.text(
            'Some other text ...',
            150,
            120,
            true
        ).attr({
            zIndex: 5
        }).css({
            width: '150px',
            height: '50px',
            'overflow-y': 'scroll'
        }).add();
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nv82mzr7/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text

Comment: Thanku, didn't think this css would wrk here. Is there any way to add a table in place of textarea.

Comment: Hi @LEKSHMI SURESH, As you can see in the example - it works. Please check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w4z1qofk/ to learn how you can add a table.

Comment: Thanku for the demo @ppotaczek. But for me in chart.renderer.text, the option html true was not working and the content was shown as plain text. Does that option work for all versions of highcharts.

Comment: Which Highcharts version do you use? Here is an example with Highcharts v 4.0.0: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ge9a3pLt/

Comment: No I mentioned the case with table, anyway it worked. Thanku. I was trying for a way to export the table, but there the html is not used, only exported with plain text. Is there anyway you have done it.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not supported. You would have to draw the table by `Highcharts.SVGRenderer`: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer

Comment: Thanku for saving my time. Will try with SVGRenderer.